# SELECT query in sqlDelight doesn't return nothing although insert operation works fine

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

I was developing an Kotlin Multiplatform app, where I'm using SQLDelight as localDatabase, and I get into a trubble when I try to recover all the data keep in it.

So, my insert operation works fine, in order I hace the following implementation of my SQLDelight queries, and changes() method return 1 row modificated, when I invoke the insert operation.

But when I call the SELECT operation, the return data is empty.

database.sq

```
CREATE TABLE characters (
    key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    image TEXT NOT NULL,
    numberEpisodes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    location TEXT NOT NULL
);

insertCharacter:
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO characters (id, name,image, numberEpisodes, location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);

selectAll:  //This is the query which return empty array.
    SELECT id, name, image, numberEpisodes, location FROM characters ORDER BY name;

delete:
    DELETE FROM characters WHERE id = :id;

selectById:
    SELECT id,name, image, numberEpisodes, location FROM characters WHERE id = :id;

rowAffected:
    SELECT changes();
```

Regarding the model of data which I try to recover is this:

```
data class CharacterModel(
    val id: String,
    val image: String,
    val numberEpisodes: Long,
    val location: String,
    val name: String
)
```

And this is my repository level:

```
override fun selectAllCharacter(): WrapperResponse<ArrayList<CharacterModel>> {
        var characters: ArrayList<CharacterModel> = ArrayList()
        return try{
                queries.selectAll().executeAsList().map {
                characters.add(
                    CharacterModel(
                        id = it.id.toString(),
                        image = it.image,
                        numberEpisodes = it.numberEpisodes,
                        location = it.location,
                        name = it.name
                    )
                )
            }
            WrapperResponse.Sucess(characters)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            WrapperResponse.Error("Se ha producido un error")
        }
    }
```

Also, I see that at repository and viewmodel level, the data is empty too, so what is not working, is the query of the .sq generate file, but I swear is correct in base of my data model.